# how to handle subscribe function in change event of select tag of angular 5, triggering many times

Tags: angular

Following is my DataService.ts

export class DataService {

```
dataObs$: any;
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {

}
getUsers() {
    return this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
}

getPostsById(id: number, refresh: boolean = false) {
    if(refresh) {
        this.http.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=${id}`)
            .subscribe(data => {
                this.dataObs$.next(data);
            });
    }
    return this.dataObs$.asObservable();
}
```

}

Following is my component class
export class CacheComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

```
constructor(private dataService: DataService) { }

users: any = [];
table: any = [];
sub: any;
sub2: any;
userid: number;
sortColumn: string;
ngOnInit() {
    this.sortColumn = 'id';
    this.sub = this.dataService.getUsers().subscribe(res => {
        this.users = res;
    });
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.sub)
        this.sub.unsubscribe();

    if (this.sub2)
        this.sub2.unsubscribe();
}

onUserChanged(userobjStr: any) {
    let userObj = JSON.parse(userobjStr);
    this.userid = userObj.id;
    this.sub2 = this.dataService.getPostsById(userObj.id, true).subscribe(res => {
        this.table = res;
    });
}

onPostChanged(val: number) {

}

getDataAgain() {
    // this.sub = this.dataService.getall().subscribe(res => {
    //     this.table = res;
    // })
}

sort(column: string) {

}
```

}

My question is, every time i change the select tag my code is re-subscribing the service and getting all callbacks from beggining.

onUserChanged is my first dropdown which is used to change users, postChanged is my other dropdown which is used to display only particular post of that user. But, initially want to display all posts, with second dropdown i want to display specific post only. But, i want to achieve this using caching all post of that user and filter based on that. I am unable to post html code, reason i am describing.

Answer (score 0):

Seems you didn't explain the execution flow clearly that which function is connected with select tag. This would be a quick fix,

```
onUserChanged(userobjStr: any) {
    let userObj = JSON.parse(userobjStr);
    this.userid = userObj.id;
    this.sub2 = this.dataService.getPostsById(userObj.id, true).subscribe(res => {
        this.table = res;
    }).unsubscribe();
}
```

It immediately cancels the subscription and initiates a new in the next cycle. 
If you can elaborate the problem, I would give the exact solution.

Answer (score 0):

You are mainly interested in the first result returned from your API. To achieve that you can use RXJS operator "takeWhile" and apply conditional check for unsubscribing it.Find the example below:

```
onUserChanged(userobjStr: any) {
    let userObj = JSON.parse(userobjStr);
    this.userid = userObj.id;
    this.dataService.getPostsById(userObj.id,true)
     .pipe(takeWhile(val=>val))
     .subscribe(res => {
        this.table = res;
    });
}
```

This code will wait until you received some not null value from your API and then stop. So, you will not end up having many subscription running in the background and be sure that first not null value will be received.